# Backbone: prevent this.render() from doing reset to the input fields

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, render, marionette, reset

My form has list of documents, one input field and button.

**The Scenario:**

1. I enter the product name in the input field.
2. I click on the search button
3. The documents having the that name is rendered but the input field is reset (becomes blank)

How can i prevent the render function from resetting the input field?
This is a part of my code:

*The View*

```
View.DocumentsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({      
    events : {
        "click button.js-Doc-search": "search",
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = this.model.get("list");
    },
    onRender : function(){      
        // Do something to prevent the reset of the input
    }
});
```

*The Controller*

```
documentsView.on("documents:search", function(name) {
    var that = this;
    var fetchingDocuments = this.request("document:entities", name);
    $.when(fetchingDocuments).done(function(documents) {            
        that.model = documents;
        that.collection = documents.get("list");
        that.render();  
    });
});
```

Comment: It is unclear why the input field becomes blank. My guess is something in the `search` methods clears it. Can you share the `search` method of the DocumentView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply save the value in input field to the current view, model etc when search is clicked, like `this.searchTerm = this.$el.find('selector for input').val()`;

And when render is called you can just set it back to the input field.

```
View.DocumentsView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({      
  events : {
    "click button.js-Doc-search": "search",
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.collection = this.model.get("list");
  },
  onRender : function(){      
    // Do the rendering
    if(this.searchTerm)
      this.$el.find('selector for input').val(this.searchTerm);
  }
});
```

or if you use a library like [rivets](http://rivetsjs.com/) to always keep the value and input in sync

it'll be as simple as

```
<input rv-value="view.searchterm"/>
```

once you configure and bind rivets.